# get total count of related records on insert, update, delete

Tags: apex, trigger

I have a triggerHandler that fires the function below. Based on my System.debug logs, I know it fires on all 3 `after` trigger events: `insert, update, delete`.

```
// when an auction is created, updated, or deleted,
// get the total number of auctions related to the same incoming auction.Listing__c (Lookup).
// 
public static void updateNoOfAuctionCyclesOnRelatedListing(List<Auction__c> newAuctions, Map<Id, Auction__c> oldMap, Boolean isDelete) {
    Set<Id> listingIds = new Set<Id>();

    List<Auction__c> auctions = (isDelete) ? oldMap.values() : newAuctions;

    for (Auction__c auction : auctions) {
        // if trigger is on insert and is not delete
        if (oldMap == null  && !isDelete) {
            listingIds.add(auction.Listing__c );
            continue;
        }

        // if auction listing is different from old auction listing
        // update the new listing an the old listing
        Auction__c oldAuction = oldMap.get(auction.Id);
        if (auction.Listing__c  != oldAuction.Listing__c ) {
            listingIds.add(auction.Listing__c );
            listingIds.add(oldAuction.Listing__c );
        }
    }

    listingIds.remove(null);
    if (!listingIds.isEmpty()) {
        Map<Id, pba__Listing__c  > listingMap = new Map<Id, pba__Listing__c>();

        for (Id id : listingIds) {
            listingMap.put(id, new pba__Listing__c(Id = id, No_of_Auction_Cycles__c  = 0));
        }

        for (AggregateResult ar : [
            SELECT count(Id),
            Listing__c
            FROM Auction__c
            WHERE Listing__c in :listingIds
            GROUP BY Listing__c
        ]) {
            Id id = (Id) ar.get('Listing__c');
            listingMap.get(id).No_of_Auction_Cycles__c  = (Integer) ar.get('expr0');
        }

        update listingMap.values(); 
    }
}
```

all of the asserts pass except the last one, which asserts that when a deletion of an auction happens, it updates the one related listing that holds the total number of related auctions (No_of_Auction_Cycles__c). The the last assert returns 2

```
@isTest static void updateNoOfAuctionCyclesOnRelatedListing() {
    pba__Listing__c l1 = new pba__Listing__c();
    pba__Listing__c l2 = new pba__Listing__c();

    insert new List<pba__Listing__c>{l1, l2};

    Auction__c a1            = new Auction__c();
    a1.Listing__c            = l1.Id;
    a1.Auction_Number__c     = '1';
    a1.Auction_Start_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2017, 08, 08);
    a1.Auction_Program__c    = 'Bankruptcy';
    a1.Starting_Bid__c       = 1;
    a1.Auction_End_Date__c   = Date.newInstance(2017, 08, 09);        

    Auction__c a2           = new Auction__c();
    a2.Listing__c            = l1.Id;
    a2.Auction_Number__c     = '2';
    a2.Auction_Start_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2017, 08, 08);
    a2.Auction_Program__c    = 'Bankruptcy';
    a2.Starting_Bid__c       = 1;
    a2.Auction_End_Date__c   = Date.newInstance(2017, 08, 09);  

    Auction__c a3            = new Auction__c();
    a3.Listing__c            = l1.Id;
    a3.Auction_Number__c     = '3';
    a3.Auction_Start_Date__c = Date.newInstance(2017, 08, 08);
    a3.Auction_Program__c    = 'Bankruptcy';
    a3.Starting_Bid__c       = 1;
    a3.Auction_End_Date__c   = Date.newInstance(2017, 08, 09);  

    insert new List<Auction__c>{a1, a2, a3};

    // Listing 1.No_of_Auction_Cycles__c should equal 3, cause there are 3 auctions
    System.assertEquals(3, [SELECT No_of_Auction_Cycles__c FROM pba__Listing__c WHERE Id = :l1.Id].No_of_Auction_Cycles__c);

    a2.Listing__c = l2.Id;

    update a2;        

    // Listing 1.No_of_Auction_Cycles__c should equal 2, cause I updated one of the auctions to not be related to Listing 1
    System.assertEquals(2, [SELECT No_of_Auction_Cycles__c FROM pba__Listing__c WHERE Id = :l1.Id].No_of_Auction_Cycles__c);

    delete a3;

    // Listing 1.No_of_Auction_Cycles__c should equal 1, cause one auction was reassigned to a different listing, and the other was delete
    System.assertEquals(1, [SELECT No_of_Auction_Cycles__c FROM pba__Listing__c WHERE Id = :l1.Id].No_of_Auction_Cycles__c);


}
```

Comment: Don't neglect **`undelete`**. Regardless, this seems like a much better task for **[DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)**.

Comment: @AdrianLarson good point....

Comment: @AdrianLarson I'm actually using your suggested design pattern for this trigger logic :D https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/140659/trigger-handler-whats-its-purpose

Comment: But you don't need to write a single line of your own code for this functionality! A good general rule is: when you can write less code, do so. The handler itself is somewhat peripheral here.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I'm looking into DLRS. I'll definitely  close this question if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use DLRS here.

- Parent Object: **pba__Listing__c**
- Relationship Field: **Listing__c**
- Child Object: **Auction__c**
- Field to Aggregate: **Id**
- Aggregate Operation: **Count**
- Aggregate Result Field: **No_of_Auction_Cycles__c**

A side note, you can get a `Map<Id, AggregateResult>` using alias.

```
Map<Id, AggregateResult> listingToCount = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([
    SELECT Listing__c Id, count(Id) records
    //     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ alias the parent field to Id,
    // and voila the built in map constructor will work

    FROM Auction // WHERE, etc...
]);
```

Comment: it's taking for ever to deploy the trigger that the app created....