# Test cases in a list

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

I am trying to get code coverage for my list/loop but no matter what I try I am missing something and could use a hand if possible as I am trying to learn more about Apex.

Trigger:

```
trigger CaseNoneBusinessHrs on Case (before insert) {
DateTime now =system.Now();
BusinessHours bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault=true];
Boolean isWithin= BusinessHours.isWithin(bh.id, now);

    if(isWithin){
    Return;
}else{
    List<Case> numberofcases = [SELECT ID FROM CASE where CaseAge__c<=:1 AND origin='Web Email'];

    for(case cas:trigger.new){
        if(cas.origin == 'Web Email'){
            if(numberofcases.size() == 10) {
                cas.EmailSurge__c = true;
            }
            if(numberofcases.size() == 25) {
                cas.EmailSurge25__c = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically it is checking if a case is created within business hours from email and if not are there 10 others created via email in the last hour, if so it updates the surge checkbox.

Now I have my test class that for the life of me I cannot get to cover the code and hoping for assistance please to get coverage.

Test Class:

```
    @isTest static void testList(){
            List<Case> Cases = new List<Case>();

    for(integer i=0; i<10; i++){
        Case ca = new Case();
        ca.Subject = 'Test Subject - Field Test ' + i;
        ca.Description = 'Test Description - Field Test ' + i;
        ca.Origin = 'Web Email';
        ca.Type = 'Other';
        ca.Reason = 'Other';
        ca.EmailSurge__c = true;
        ca.EmailSurge25__c = true;
    }
    Test.startTest();
    insert cases;
    Test.stopTest();
    Cases = [SELECT EmailSurge__c FROM Case];
    for (Case record: Cases){
        System.assert(record.EmailSurge__c == true);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong that this will not generate code coverage for the list? what do I need to cover the trigger?

Comment: Does your test pass? Please include the entire trigger and clearly indicate which lines are not covered.

Comment: Hi Adrian - I have edited trigger to include the entire trigger (business hours check) and the trigger works in testing, my current coverage is 41% since I am able to do a test method to cover the business hours check easy but I cannot get this test method for the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This trigger pattern is going to cause nightmares. When you write your unit tests, they will either check very little about what your code does (and provide variable coverage), or they will fail intermittently, depending on when you run them. First of all, you should move your code out of the trigger body and into an `Apex Class`, which is something you should do no matter what pattern you apply. Then, I would consider making your `isWithin` variable `@TestVisible` so you can overwrite the value when you write your unit tests.

```
public with sharing class CaseEmailSurgeService
{
    @TestVisible static Boolean isWithinBusinessHours
    {
        get
        {
            if (isWithinBusinessHours == null)
            {
                isWithinBusinessHours = BusinessHours.isWithin(
                    [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault = true].Id,
                    Datetime.now()
                );
            }
            return isWithinBusinessHours;
        }
        set;
    }
}
```

Then, in your test, you can control whether or not you are running within business hours, independently of when your test is run.

```
@IsTest static void testMyFunctionWithinBusinessHours()
{
    CaseEmailSurgeService.isWithinBusinessHours = true;

    // data setup

    Test.startTest();
        // functionality to be tested
    Test.stopTest();

    // assertions
}
@IsTest static void testMyFunctionOutsideBusinessHours()
{
    CaseEmailSurgeService.isWithinBusinessHours = false;

    // data setup

    Test.startTest();
        // functionality to be tested
    Test.stopTest();

    // assertions
}
```

Please also note that there are system functions for **`assertEquals`** and **`assertNotEquals`**, which you should always prefer over `assert` for any sort of equality or inequality check. That way, if the assertion fails, you get information about what values are actually observed. You should also include an informative error message as your final parameter in these methods. While it is optional, you should consider it mandatory as it is invaluable while debugging deployment failures (if well written.).

Comment: Adrian - Thank you! This makes tons of sense and really helps with learning, I took the trail courses and was struggling but this makes sense and I appreciate the assistance! I never thought about the reason for failing is because I am in business hours right now. ----- So to confirm basically move the business hours check into its own class (your code block 1) so the trigger is just the IF section then in the test class I can use your code block 2 to effectively turn business hours on and off for testing?

Comment: You should move *all* your code out of the trigger and look into trigger handler patterns. There are many flavors out there, but basically your trigger should only delegate which events and records are happening to some other class, and not specify *how* to do anything. Your handler typically should compose actions and filters, and still not answer any of the how questions. Your service and/or filter layers should then get to that granular level. See also [my answer here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/140668/2995) where I explain in greater detail.

Comment: Thanks for the link and insight. I am working towards going into certification next year so all this helps with learning.

Comment: Quick follow up question, how do I reference the business hours check? trying to link it to the if check for ifWithin (line 6 of trigger) how would I reference it to check if is within business hours? -- Thanks again!

Comment: You would need to flat out make it public if you try to leave the rest of the logic in your trigger. But you shouldn't do that. You should move *all* the logic into your class, but move the logic conditional on `isWithin` into a separate method.

Answer (score 2):

You're running a `before insert` trigger, but your trigger's action depends on querying the database for *existing* Cases - Cases that aren't part of the current trigger invocation but have already been committed to the database.

In addition to sfdcfox's and Adrian's comments, you'll need to insert test data in two DML statements: the first (with 10, or 25, or possibly different values in multiple test cases) will seed the database with the right number of existing Cases to match your query, and the second will result in your code identifying a surge event by inserting one or more *new* Cases.

Note that this raises an issue with your business logic as well: if more than 10 or 25 Cases are inserted in a single transaction, but *don't* already exist in the org, your code will fail to take action when you want it to. You may want to add some logic to account for the case when the current DML operation results in a surge when added to what's already in the database.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you forgot to add the records to the list:

```
for(integer i=0; i<10; i++){
    Case ca = new Case();
    ca.Subject = 'Test Subject - Field Test ' + i;
    ca.Description = 'Test Description - Field Test ' + i;
    ca.Origin = 'Web Email';
    ca.Type = 'Other';
    ca.Reason = 'Other';
    // These should be set by the trigger!
    //ca.EmailSurge__c = true;
    //ca.EmailSurge25__c = true;
    // Don't forget to add the cases to the list!
    cases.add(ca);
}
```

You might need to add some more logic to handle the 25 surge scenario, and you might also need to add specific test logic to your trigger logic to support running the trigger during business hours but while running the test.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox - I made the change and for some reason I am still not getting coverage from line 10 (List<cases> numberofcases) down even with the change you suggested.

Comment: @CraigPhoenix Right. As I said, your test can only current work "out of hours." You'll want to use `Test.isRunningTest()` or a static variable somewhere to bypass the business hours check, otherwise you can only run your tests after business hours.

Comment: @sfdcfox Indeed, and I wrote an answer on how to do that. Nice catch about not adding to the collection though. I didn't even see that!

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for clarifying! I truly appreciate you and Adrian Larson for the assistance!