# Cross object field Update trigger

Tags: apex, after-trigger

I have two custom objects booking__c and car__c. I am trying to write a trigger when On Booking, selected car availability should change from true to false. (booking__c and car__c have lookup relationship)

```
trigger Simpsons_T01_updateInObjects on Booking__c(after insert, after update) {

    list<car__c> carlist=new list<car__c>();

    for(booking__c b:trigger.new)
    {
        car__c objcar=new car__c();
        if(b.car__c!=null)
        {
            objcar.Car_available__c=false;
            carlist.add(objcar);
        }
    }
    update carlist;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there. The code is bulkiefied and you checked on the right condition.
What's missing is an Id for each instance of Car__c object you created: without it the update will always fail, because without an unique identifier the system cannot know which record update.

The Id you're looking for is in the lookup field, so you can assign it to the Car's instance:

```
for(Booking__c b : Trigger.New) {
    if (b.car__c != null) {
        Car__c objcar = new Car__c(Id = b.car__c); // Set the Id
        objcar.Car_available__c = false;
        carList.add(objcar);
    }
}
```

By the way, there is no need to create a new instance outside the if block.
You should also consider to move the trigger's logic in a [handler](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/140668/62544) class.